# Subdivision modifier's name is red

Tags: modifiers

My subdivision modifier's name is red preventing me from using it. I followed a tutorial and this happened.

Comment: What another modifiers are used? I don't think this is happening on default cube, right?

Comment: Increase the levels of subdivisions so that it is higher than 0

Comment: Hello :). It can also mean, that you enabled Simplify, with 0 max levels :). Please add an image of your modifier settings.

Comment: How do I post an image 1st time using this site

Answer (score 3):

When the modifiers settings are zeroed out the modifier has no effect. So it shows a red icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the *Render Properties* there is tab *Simplify*.

If active, it can clamp all the subdivisions to a maximum number using the *Max Subdivisions* setting.